# How to create custom shaped TabBar with cut out in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i do understand how to create a custom "tabBar" in swiftui. I have my routing manager and stuff. Everything works fine. But I can not figure out how to create cut out around my button like you can see in the picture. Thanks a lot for help.[image: Much needed effect]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create your own shape for tabbar. Here is an example you can play with:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabBar: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            TabBarShape()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(height: 80)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 2, x: 0, y: -1)
                .overlay(
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Text("")
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(30)
                    }).offset(x: 0, y: -36)
                )
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct TabBarShape: Shape {

    private enum Constants {
        static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20
        static let buttonRadius: CGFloat = 30
        static let buttonPadding: CGFloat = 5
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: .init(x: 0, y: rect.height))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: 0, y: rect.height - Constants.cornerRadius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: Constants.cornerRadius, y: Constants.cornerRadius), radius: Constants.cornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)

        let lineEnd = rect.width/2 - 2 * Constants.buttonPadding - Constants.buttonRadius
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: lineEnd, y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: lineEnd, y: Constants.buttonPadding), radius: Constants.buttonPadding, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: rect.width/2, y: Constants.buttonPadding), radius: Constants.buttonPadding + Constants.buttonRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)

        let lineStart = rect.width/2 + 2 * Constants.buttonPadding + Constants.buttonRadius
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: lineStart, y: Constants.buttonPadding), radius: Constants.buttonPadding, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)

        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.width - Constants.cornerRadius, y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: rect.width - Constants.cornerRadius, y: Constants.cornerRadius), radius: Constants.cornerRadius, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        path.close()

        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}

struct TabBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabBar()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, just the way i wanted... have to play with shapes a bit more. thanks

Comment: For an easier way to create the shape: https://github.com/ryanlintott/ShapeUp